# How do I know when an asynchronous socket read ends?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous read method...

```
private void read(IAsyncResult ar) {
        //Get the Server State Object
        ServerState state = (ServerState)ar.AsyncState;

        //read from the socket
        int readCount = state.socket.EndReceive(ar);

        //check if reading is done, move on if so, trigger another read if not
        if (readCount > 0) {
            //purge the buffer and start another read
            state.purgeBuffer();
            state.socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ServerState.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(read), state);
        }
        else {
            //all bytes have been read, dispatch the message
            dispatch(state);
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am having is that *read* is only 0 if the connection is closed. How do I say, this is the end of that message and pass the data on to the dispatcher, while leaving the socket open to accept new messages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not rely on what is in the TCP buffer. You must process the incoming bytes as a stream somewhere. You can't really know whether its complete. Only one layer above can know when the message completed.

Example:
If you read HTTP responses the HTTP header will contain the byte count which is in the HTTP body. So you know how much to read.

You only know how much to read if the data follows a certain protocol and you interprete it. Imagine you receive a file over the socket. The first thing you would receive is the file size. Without that you would never know how much to read.

Comment: So I need to send a message length at the begging of the message to tell when the message is complete?

Comment: Exactly that. Without that you have a neverending stream of data like the audio streams in internet radio streams.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your messages fit a particular format so that you can distinguish when they start and when end. Even if it is a stream of data it should be sent in packets.

One option is to send length of message first and then you know how much data to expect. But problem with that is if you loose sync you can never recover and you will never know what is message length and what is its content. It is good to use some special marking sequence to know when message begins. It is is not 100% error proof (sequence might appear in data) but certainly helps and allows to recover from sync loose. This is particularly important when reading from a binary stream like socket.

Even ancient RS232 serial protocol had its frame and stop bit to know when you got all the data.